# How to Create A Horizontal ScrollBar in Tab Container (Not Vertical Scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, tabs

I would like to create a horizontal scrollbar for Ajax Tab Container when tab headers overflow. I can create a vertical scrollbar for it but I want horizontal scrollbar instead.

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Plan to Achieve:**

### [image]

This is my codes:

**Create Tabs Dynamically:**

```
    //Aspx file:
<asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:scriptmanager>

        </div>
        <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <contenttemplate>

        <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
        </contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>

//Cs file:
protected void RETRIEVE_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
            container.ID = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
            container.EnableViewState = false;
            container.Tabs.Clear();

            if (ListBox1.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Value == "1")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Label tabContent = new Label();
                    tabContent.ID += item.Value;
                    tabContent.Text += item.Value;

                    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                    panel.HeaderText += item.Text;
                    container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                    panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        Label tabContent = new Label();
                        tabContent.ID += item.Value;
                        tabContent.Text += item.Value;

                        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                        panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
                        container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                        panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
                    }
                }
            }

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
```

**Create Scrollbar for Overflowing Tab Header:**

```
    //Aspx file:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(function () {

           $(".ajax__tab_header").html("<div style='height:80px;width:1200px;' >" + $(".ajax__tab_header").html() + "</div>");

       })
   </script>
   <style>
       .ajax__tab_header {
           height: 40px !important;
           width: 200px;
           overflow: scroll;
           overflow-y: hidden;
       }
   </style>
```

**Question:** How to create a **horizontal scrollbar**, **not** vertical scrollbar when tab headers overflow.
Appreciate if someone can help me on this, thanks a lot!!

Regards,

Felicia

Answer (score 0):

try specifying overflow for both x & y by setting

```
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

instead of

```
overflow:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek Siddhu, have tried this method but doesn't work :(

Comment: Read the question again, had missed a point earlier. Apply the overflow property in the parent container in which tab headers are present and not the tab headers itself.

Comment: hi, have tried on this method but is still the same result. I have updated my codes to show more of my codes. Please take a look thanks!